# What is the Citrix\System32 folder and how does it differ from System32 folder

Tags: citrix

I am exploring a Citrix environment and noted that there is are two System32 folders one in the usual location and another under a Citrix folder.    What is the difference.   When is one used and when is the other used.    If I have application specific dll's that I normally put in the System32 folder, should they be in the Citrix\System32 folder instead?

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not put anything in System32 folders! Neither in the regular Windows ones (32 bit and 64 bit), nor in the Citrix one. Use your application's installation directory.
2. The Citrix\System32 folder is used by Citrix only. Don't mess with it.

Comment: Why should you not put anything in System32 folders?

Comment: Because if everyone does it, you get the infamous "DLL hell". Stick to you own turf (your install directory).